# Threads on MacOS: libc++abi.dylib: terminating

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos

I have simple program to call threads what call threads. I'm sure that I'm missing something obviously. Belowe is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

vector<thread> threads;

void Next(int amount) {
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) threads.push_back(thread(Next,amount-1));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int amount = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) threads.push_back(thread(Next,amount-1));

cout << threads.size() << endl;
for (auto& th : threads) {
    if (th.joinable()) {
        th.join();
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

The output is different, for example:

1.

```
2
```

2.

```
2
libc++abi.dylib: terminating
Abort trap: 6
```

3.

```
2
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: thread::join failed: No such process
Abort trap: 6
```

I was searching any helpful information in internet and unfortunately didn't found anything.

There is my second code what is working, but I wrote it good?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void Next(int amount) {
vector<thread> threads;

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) threads.push_back(thread(Next,amount-1));

cout << threads.size() << endl;
    for (auto& th : threads) {
        if (th.joinable()) {
            th.join();
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int amount = 2;

vector<thread> threads;

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) threads.push_back(thread(Next,amount-1));

cout << threads.size() << endl;
for (auto& th : threads) {
    if (th.joinable()) {
        th.join();
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

With mutex ( still problem ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

mutex mtx;
vector <thread> threads;

using namespace std;

void Next(int amount) {
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    mtx.lock();
    threads.push_back(thread(Next,amount-1));
    mtx.unlock();
}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int amount = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    mtx.lock();
    threads.push_back(thread(Next,amount-1));
    mtx.unlock();
}

cout << threads.size() << endl;

for (auto& th : threads) {
    if (th.joinable()) {
        th.join();
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which thread owns the data you're manipulating? If it's shared you may need to use a mutex.

Comment: @tadman, I added mutex like here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/
I am not sure if it is good, still no work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition on access to the `vector` 'threads'.